# When should the second drupal_bootstrap() parameter be used?

Tags: 7, bootstrapping

The parameters accepted from [drupal_bootstrap()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/7) are two; the second is defined as follows:

> `$new_phase`: A boolean, set to FALSE if calling `drupal_bootstrap()` from inside a function called from `drupal_bootstrap()` (recursion).

I am not clear what that means, considering that [statistics_exit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!statistics!statistics.module/function/statistics_exit/7) calls `drupal_bootstrap()` using just one argument, thus using the default value (`TRUE`) for the second one.
`hook_exit()` is invoked from [_drupal_bootstrap_page_cache()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap_page_cache/7), and `statistics_exit()` should be considered a function called from `drupal_bootstrap()` that calls `drupal_bootstrap()`.

Yet, `statistics_exit()` is not using `FALSE` as second argument of `drupal_bootstrap()`.

The only functions I found that use `FALSE` as second parameter are [module_hook_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_hook_info/7), and [_drupal_bootstrap_page_cache()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap_page_cache/7), which contain the following code.

```
  // module_hook_info()
  // This function is indirectly invoked from bootstrap_invoke_all(), in which
  // case common.inc, subsystems, and modules are not loaded yet, so it does not
  // make sense to support hook groups resp. lazy-loaded include files prior to
  // full bootstrap.
  if (drupal_bootstrap(NULL, FALSE) != DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL) {
    return array();
  }
```

```
  // _drupal_bootstrap_page_cache()
  // Check for a cache mode force from settings.php.
  if (variable_get('page_cache_without_database')) {
    $cache_enabled = TRUE;
  }
  else {
    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_VARIABLES, FALSE);
    $cache_enabled = variable_get('cache');
  }
```

From the code of the first function I could understand I should use `FALSE` when I need to get the current bootstrap phase, and in that case I would use `NULL` as first argument.
From the code of the second function, I could understand that the second parameter is an internal parameter, I should not pass in my functions, as the only case a function of mine is being called from `drupal_bootstrap()` (also indirectly, through a function that is called from `drupal_bootstrap()`) is when I implement `hook_boot()`, or `hook_exit()`.

Did I misunderstand what said in the `drupal_bootstrap()` documentation? If it so, when exactly should a call to `drupal_bootstrap()` use a value for the second parameter that is different from its default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking more closely, I can't say why `statistics_exit()` doesn't use the second parameter, but to answer your question...

The `drupal_bootstrap()` function only ever needs to be called with `$new_phase = FALSE` to prevent an infinite loop inside the core bootstrap code. Unless you're modifying core, *you'll always want to leave the second parameter at its default value* (`TRUE`).

The key is in this part of `drupal_bootstrap()`:

```
// When not recursing, store the phase name so it's not forgotten while
// recursing.
if ($new_phase) {
  $final_phase = $phase;
}
```

Calls to `drupal_bootstrap()` outside the bootstrap process always specify the final phase to bootstrap to (or only get the current phase, in which case, the second parameter doesn't matter). When you call `drupal_boostrap()`, you'll be initiating the bootstrap process and setting the `static $final_phase` variable, so you'll need `$new_phase = TRUE`.

Comment: I would add that there are many Drupal core functions that use a parameter though to be use from Drupal core, which uses it and sets it to a value different from the default value. In this case, `$new_phase` could be used also from contrubuted modules, in a function that calls `drupal_bootstrap()` and that is called from `drupal_bootstrap()`. Probably there are very few modules that need to use `$new_phase`.